# PHP code to show form on multiple wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my wordpress templates  that displays a form on every wordpress page. I'm trying to get it to only display on pages that I specify.

I have tried the following code which only works for one page:

```html
<?php if( $post->ID == 346) { ?>

     <?php email_form(get_the_content()); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `if(in_array($post->ID, [id1, id2]))`? Or try add some extra attributes to post (eg: tag, metadata), then detect in this code, and display form. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post

Comment: This worked....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
 global $post;
 $post_slug = $post->post_name;
 $pages = array('slug-1','slug-2','slug-3');//Add pages where you want to show the form in this array
 if(in_array($post_slug, $pages)){
  email_form(get_the_content());//If current page is in array, display form
 }
```